# How to open new window when using javascript to post to a form?

Tags: javascript

I have a form like so:

```
    <form method="post" action="task.cfm" name="lookup" id="lookup">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="emailAddress" value="">
    </form>
```

And I'm posting to this form using this link:

```
<a href="javascript:document.lookup.action.value='search';document.lookup.emailAddress.value='<cfoutput>#VARIABLES.decryptedEmailAddress#</cfoutput>';document.lookup.submit();">View User details</a>
```

The link works, but I'm trying to get it to open in a new window. target="_blank" does not work in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the target attribute to your form:

```
<form method="post" action="task.cfm" name="lookup" id="lookup" target="_blank">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="emailAddress" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you place the target="_blank" attribute on the anchor, or on the form tag? Try placing it on the form tag.